# Adding .htaccess to Cordova

Tags: .htaccess, cordova

I'd like to add a .htaccess to rewrite all paths to relative ones within Cordova.

At default, the .htaccess seems to be ignored. For Apache servers, you have to activate the support of these files.

Is there any equivalent option for Cordova, that works with every platform?

Comment: There is no .htaccess within Cordova as there is no server - the html is opened directly in a browser on the client - what is the problem with file access that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I think there has to be a server, because files are opened within http://localhost:8000. Normally, browsers open files using file://.

I'd like to add a rewrite rule to redirect every request to index.html, because this file handles the generation of the content.